# How to Define Custom/Use Custom Resource Methods in Installation Scripts

Tags: install, script

What's the proper way to define functions used in installation scripts? I have a long list of data to add in a module, and I'd like to avoid writing a long serial script or just including functions at the bottom or top of the installation script files.

Specifically, I'm wondering if there's a `.php` file that can be included for the `data` or `sql` scripts.

UPDATE: See my answer.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear (at least to me). Can you provide a small example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `resources` node for the installation script, you can define your own class to be used. `$this`, then, in the installation script will be of class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Catalog_Setup` in this example.

```
<resources>
    <abc_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Test_Abc</module>
            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Catalog_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </abc_setup>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way should be using an own Setup.php.

You may use http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources as an entry point.